# DataGridView on load event not populating

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, datagridview

As a fairly new user to VB.NET, I am confused as to why a DataGridView is not populating when I call sub on form_load. I have been stuggling with this and googling for some time, but still no joy. I know it is my error and not up enough yet on debugging to know exactly what to look for. I am calling the sub with '**DGVmod.fillPostings()**' in frmMain on form_load event. The code is in a Module. Does that make a difference? Can someone please show me my basic error. Many thanks

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module DGVmod

    Private da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Private ds As DataSet
    Private dtSource As DataTable

    Private PageCount As Integer
    Private maxRec As Integer
    Private pageSize As Integer
    Private currentPage As Integer
    Private recNo As Integer

    Sub fillPostings()

        Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.storageConnectionString)

        'Set the DataAdapter's query.
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Postings", conn)
        ds = New DataSet()

        ' Fill the DataSet.
        da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "Postings")
        da.Fill(ds, "Postings")

        ' Set the source table.
        dtSource = ds.Tables("Postings")


    End Sub

    Sub btnprevious()

        If Not CheckFillButton() Then Return

        If currentPage = PageCount Then
            recNo = pageSize * (currentPage - 2)
        End If

        currentPage = currentPage - 1

        'Check if you are already at the first page.
        If currentPage < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You are at the First Page!")
            currentPage = 1
            Return
        Else
            recNo = pageSize * (currentPage - 1)
        End If

        fillPostings()
        loadpages()

    End Sub

    Sub btnnext()

        'If the user did not click the "Fill Grid" button then Return
        If Not CheckFillButton() Then Return

        'Check if the user clicked the "Fill Grid" button.
        If pageSize = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Set the Page Size, and then click the ""Fill Grid"" button!")
            Return
        End If

        currentPage = currentPage + 1

        If currentPage > PageCount Then
            currentPage = PageCount

            'Check if you are already at the last page.
            If recNo = maxRec Then
                MessageBox.Show("You are at the Last Page!")
                Return
            End If
        End If

        fillPostings()
        loadpages()

    End Sub

    Sub btnlast()

        If Not CheckFillButton() Then Return

        ' Check if you are already at the last page.
        If recNo = maxRec Then
            MessageBox.Show("You are at the Last Page!")
            Return
        End If

        currentPage = PageCount

        recNo = pageSize * (currentPage - 1)
        fillPostings()
        loadpages()

    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayPageInfo()

        frmMain.txtDisplayPageNo.Text = "Page " & currentPage.ToString & "/ " & PageCount.ToString

    End Sub

    Sub fillgrid()

        Try
            'Set the start and max records. 
            pageSize = CInt(frmMain.cmbPageSize.Text)
            maxRec = frmMain.DGV.Rows.Count
            PageCount = maxRec \ pageSize

            ' Adjust the page number if the last page contains a partial page.
            If (maxRec Mod pageSize) > 0 Then
                PageCount = PageCount + 1
            End If

            'Initial seeings
            currentPage = 1
            recNo = 0

            ' Display the content of the current page.

            fillPostings()
            loadpages()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub loadpages()

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim startRec As Integer
        Dim endRec As Integer
        Dim dtTemp As DataTable
        'Dim dr As DataRow

        'Duplicate or clone the source table to create the temporary table.
        dtTemp = dtSource.Clone

        If currentPage = PageCount Then
            endRec = maxRec
        Else
            endRec = pageSize * currentPage
        End If

        startRec = recNo

        'Copy the rows from the source table to fill the temporary table.
        For i = startRec To endRec - 1
            dtTemp.ImportRow(dtSource.Rows(i))
            recNo = recNo + 1
        Next

        frmMain.DGV.DataSource = dtTemp
        DisplayPageInfo()
        'fillPostings()
    End Sub

    Sub btnfirst()

        If Not CheckFillButton() Then Return

        ' Check if you are already at the first page.
        If currentPage = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You are at the First Page!")
            Return
        End If

        currentPage = 1
        recNo = 0

        fillPostings()
        loadpages()

    End Sub

    Private Function CheckFillButton() As Boolean

        'Check if the user clicks the "Fill Grid" button.
        If pageSize = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Set the Page Size, and then click the ""Fill Grid"" button!")
            CheckFillButton = False
        Else
            CheckFillButton = True
        End If
    End Function

    Sub cmbpage()

        'Set the start and max records. 
        pageSize = CInt(frmMain.cmbPageSize.Text)
        maxRec = dtSource.Rows.Count
        PageCount = maxRec \ pageSize

        ' Adjust the page number if the last page contains a partial page.
        If (maxRec Mod pageSize) > 0 Then
            PageCount = PageCount + 1
        End If

        'Initial seeings
        currentPage = 1
        recNo = 0

        ' Display the content of the current page.

        fillPostings()
        loadpages()

    End Sub
End Module
```

frmMain load code

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'StorageDataSet1.Customers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.CustomersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StorageDataSet1.Customers)

        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'StorageDataSet.User' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.UserTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StorageDataSet.User)


        lblDate.Text = CStr(Now)

        Timer1.Start()

        rdoCustomer.Enabled = False
        rdoCustomer.Checked = True
        rdoDepartment.Enabled = False
        rdoDepartment.Checked = False

        For Each ctrl In pnlContainer.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
                AddHandler CType(ctrl, Button).MouseDown, AddressOf btn_MouseDown
            End If
        Next

        DGVmod.fillPostings()


    End Sub
```

Comment: Please attach all the relevant code of your `Form`.

Comment: Bjorn, I have posted all the code that I am using from the mod file. In frmMain load event, I am just calling sub. What code are you referring too. Thanks

Comment: Is this what you wanted Bjorn?

Comment: Yes, but could you also add the part where you populate the `DataGridView`?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. I am calling 'DGVmod.fillPostings()' to populate. Do I also have to call the fillgrid sub?

Comment: I don't see any reference to a `DataGridView`. Where is your `Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = YOUR_DATA_SOURCE`?

Comment: There isn't one. That is obviously what I am missing. How do I correct? Thanks

Comment: I see you're referring to a variable `frmMain`, where is this defined and set? Please add `MsgBox(Me is frmMain)` into `Form2_Load()` and confirm that the returned value is `True`.

Comment: That errors with: 'Login.frmMain' cannot refer to itself through its default instance; use 'Me' instead

Comment: Just to be sure, this is a vb.net winform application?

Comment: If yes, I think you should move all code from `DGVmod` module into your form. And not as `Shared` methods. Then, instead of referring to `frmMain` you just refer to `Me`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `fillpostings` function :

```
    ' Set the source table.
    dtSource = ds.Tables("Postings")
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dtSource
```

Comment: Al, the datagrid 'DGV' is in the frmMain not the mod. How do i refernece it from the mod. Thanks

Comment: I tried like this: frmMain.DGV.DataSource = dtSource but it still does not populate in frmMain load event.

Comment: Define `Public sheard dtSource as DatTable`. And call fill posting function to fill it then assinge dtSource to DGV.